# Left operand of comma operator is a reference, not call

Tags: c++

Creating a sockets program and I'm getting a few warnings here. Not sure what the problem could be:

```
    if (recv, clientWantsFile, MAX_PATH, 0) {
        ifstream file (clientWantsFile);

        if (file.is_open()) {
            send(Sub, "yes", MAX_PATH, 0);
        } else {
            send(Sub, "no", MAX_PATH, 0);
        }

        // Gets the size of the file requested
        fileSize = file.tellg();
    }
```

Warnings:

```
warning: left operand of comma operator is a reference, not call, to function 'recv' [-Waddress]
warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
warning: right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]
```

Any clue what could be wrong?

Comment: The compiler meant you might want `if (recv(clientWantsFile, MAX_PATH, 0)) {`.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks!